# Range Slider in WP8 to select a range within maximum and minimum value

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Hi I want to know is there any nuget package for wp8 for adding range slider as shown in the picture [image]

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx here it is available but it is not free. And I also found some example for wpf but not for wp8. Can any one help?

Comment: Hi @souickcse have you found the control? if yes then please share. thanks

Comment: i made my own custom range slider

Comment: that's great! please share some logic if you won't mind

Comment: currently i don't have the code but the logic is this : http://screencast.com/t/sI0ojTMHGeNq

Answer (score 1):

I finally got to making my own slider. Have put it up in GitHub. Feel free to use and contribute to the repo

https://maythecodebewithyou.wordpress.com/2015/05/20/quest-for-a-range-control/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the Coding4Fun Windows Phone Toolkit. You can see [Here](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/coding4fun-windows-phone-toolkit) how to work with the toolkit, using the slider.

Comment: but it doesn't have the range slider. it only have simple slider with some extra feature.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example [Link](http://jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/15/31-days-of-mango-day-15-the-progress-bar/). that will help you. You can use Progress Bar control as slider in windows phone. This link help me a lot to show download progress.

```
<ProgressBar Foreground="Green"
             Minimum="0"
             Value="50"
             Maximum="100"
             IsIndeterminate="False" />
```

you can set Progress Bar value by
progressBar1.Value = (int)some value;

Answer (score 0):

After one day of research I finally found this idea and hopes this helps you.

I just added two sliders into my project, say firstSider, and secondSlider. I set firstSlider width as 250px. I rotated the secondSlider to 180degree (refer the code snippet) and set width as 250px. Align firstSlider towards left and secondSlider towards right as in the code snippet and Put these two sliders inside Grid. I suggest not to use StackPanel in this case.

Like following code:

```
<Grid>
        <Slider Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SmallChange=".1" Minimum="4" Maximum="6.1" x:Name="fromSlider" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}"/>
        <Slider Margin="0,159,4,215" Minimum="6.1" Width="215" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Maximum="6.8" x:Name="toSlider" SmallChange=".1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}">
            <Slider.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-180"/>
            </Slider.RenderTransform>
        </Slider>
</Grid>
```

Change FillColor for Foreground and Background by editing a Slider Template (SliderStyle1 in my case). Like this,

```
<Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrack" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,50"/>

<Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalFill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,50">
```

That's it. You got Range Slider in Windows Phone.

Comment: Hi @bala this is good to UI representation but not easy to control. can u provide me some other idea through which i can control it as well?

Comment: @NeelBhasin Yes I know, but I couldn't find any Range Slider yet for Windows Phone. And I implemented this very well in my application and now its going good. Its also easy to implement and I got this in one working day.

Comment: basically i tried the same way previously but not able to get the second slider work properly